# HTTP Handler not working for MS office extensions

Tags: 2007, http-module, assembly-references

I am trying to map a custom HTTP handler for *.pptx files and for some reason this is not working.

My HTTP handler does nothing else other than sending an email when a powerpoint file is accessed. I have checked the code with other extensions (*.txt, *.pdf etc) and they work without any issues. I have the same problem for *.docx, *.xlsx extensions.

I have checked HTTPhandler and  handlers (System.WebServer) sections and they have correct entries.

**HTTP Handler**

```
<add verb="*" path="*.txt,*.pptx" validate="true" type="DownloadsAudit.Auditor,DownloadsAudit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=879e70535c0e166f" />
```

**Handlers**

```
<add name="PPT" path="*.pptx" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="File" />
```

This is for a MOSS 2007 application runing on IIS7. Is this a known issue? Am I missing someting?

Comment: What exactly is it doing? Is there an error? Does it just not respond? And why use an HTTPHandler rather than an HTTPModule?

Comment: Nothing happens when I access a pptx file. I get email if I access a txt file. I did not want HTTP module because I just want to track pptx extension.

Comment: I have error handling, tried debugging and the code never gets hit when a pptx file is accessed.

Comment: just to ensure the code is getting called try changing the path attribute to path="*.jpg"

Comment: One thing I came to notice while using fiddler is that, a PPTX request is not straight away directed to the file, instead it is requested through a download.aspx page. following is the url I came to get from fiddler when requesting a PPT file http://<SERVERNAME>/Docs/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=%2FDocs%2FTest%2Ftest%2Eppt&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsp2007%2FDocs%2FTest%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&FldUrl=

Answer (score 0):

Dop you need the preCondition attribute specifying in the IIS7 handler element? Otherwise it only works in Integrated pipeline and you are using Classic since it is MOSS...

Comment: I used this for registering the handler in classic mode. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx